# Passing canvas image between screens in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, image, button, canvas, app-inventor

I'm using App Inventor 2 and I had a problem with changing canvas image.

I want the user to click on button (image) then he's switched to another screen with canvas image according to the button he clicked on, and also get the image from the button and view it in the other screen's canvas.

I would make screen for each button but it's going to take a lot of time and space.

Answer (score 0):

**Use different screens wisely**

Before starting to create another screen, first you should think about is it really necessary? See also [Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html) and [SteveJG's post about advantages/disadvantages](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/ka-LS7wmWxs/wRbs70x2BgAJ), because in only one screen you also can use vertical arrangements to simulate different screens, just set the arrangements to visible = true/false as needed...